Substitute the ICON reference for nothing
On an export file of more than 2600 bookmarks from Firefox, I want to import them into Buku which seems to bug with the ICON in the html file.
So I want to substitute the ICON reference for nothing.
Here's an example, the shortest one:
ICON="data:image/png;base64,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"
I've tried
sed -e 's/^ICON=\"data:image\/png;base64,^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/][AQgw]==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}[AEIMQUYcgkosw048]=)?$\"$//g' firefox_bookmarks_copie.html > test1.html

sed -e 's/^ICON="[[:print:]]"$//gi' firefox_bookmarks_copie.html > test2.html

sed -e 's/^ICON="data:image(\/[^;]+;base64[^"]+)"$//g' firefox_bookmarks_copie.html > test3.html

awk '{gsub(/^ICON="[:print:]"$/,"");}' firefox_bookmarks_copie.html > copie4.html

AWK seems to cause me problems when saving in copie4.html
perl -0pe 's/^ICON="data:image(\/[^;]+;base64[^"]+)"$//' firefox_bookmarks_copie.html >> copie5.html

The https://regex101.com/r/sxFswz/1 site seems to be telling me that my subsitution REGEX is effective with
/ICON="data:image(\/[^;]+;base64[^"]+)"/g

Can you help me?

Use a tool designed for HTML

@ikegami  Can you elaborate?
With what tools and an example for my particular case?
I'd be grateful.

please update the question to show the expected result for the same ICON="...." line

@markp-fuso, The attributes are to be deleted.

Yes, I want to replace this whole section with nothing as I said above in a not commented enough way like:
sed -e 's/^text to find starting with ICON to delete"$//g'
except that this text is quite specific.

read the definition of sed regex syntax. You are trying to use non-sed syntax

your second sed could work but according to your linked regex101 test, your data doesn't start ICON and isn't anchored to start (^) and end ($) of line

Assumptions:

OP want's to remove ALL ICON="..." strings from the html file

Using the following (heavily) modified sample html file for demo purposes:
$ cat bm.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
... some other stuff ...
  </head>
  <body>
... some other stuff ...
      <DT><A HREF="https://www.inter.net/search/results/content/?abc" ICON="data:image/png;base64,PHN2ZyB...snip_#1...z4gPC9zdmc+">some description</A>
                                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      <DT><A HREF="https://www.inter.net/search/results/content/?abc" ICON="data:image/png;base64,PHN2ZyB...snip_#2...z4gPC9zdmc+">some description</A>
                                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  </body>
</html>

NOTE: the ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lines do not exist in bm.html but are added here to highlight the strings we're looking for
General approach - look for the consecutive strings a) ICON=", b) [^"]* (string that contains no double quotes) and c) "
One sed idea:
$ sed 's/ICON="[^"]*"//g' bm.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
... some other stuff ...
  </head>
  <body>
... some other stuff ...
      <DT><A HREF="https://www.inter.net/search/results/content/?abc" >some description</A>
      <DT><A HREF="https://www.inter.net/search/results/content/?abc" >some description</A>
  </body>
</html>

One awk idea:
$ awk '{gsub(/ICON="[^"]+"/,"")}1' bm.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
... some other stuff ...
  </head>
  <body>
... some other stuff ...
      <DT><A HREF="https://www.inter.net/search/results/content/?abc" >some description</A>
      <DT><A HREF="https://www.inter.net/search/results/content/?abc" >some description</A>
  </body>
</html>

NOTE: for this particular html file the global options (sed + /g; awk + gsub() (as opposed to sub()) is overkill since there's only one match per line; if linefeeds were to be removed (thus leaving a single long line of data) the global options insure all ICON="..." matches are replaced within a single line

The awk version works very well.
After several checks, all my bookmarks were imported into Buku without error.
Thank you for your efficient help.

Regarding your AWK code
awk '{gsub(/^ICON="[:print:]"$/,"");}' firefox_bookmarks_copie.html > copie4.html

there are at least 3 bugs.
From The GNU Awk User's Guide

A character class is only valid in a regexp inside the brackets of a
bracket expression.

therefore [:print:] must be inside [ and ], simple example
echo "ABC" | awk '/[:print:]/' # no output
echo "ABC" | awk '/[[:print:]]/'  # output is ABC

after repairing that issue result is
awk '{gsub(/^ICON="[[:print:]]"$/,"");}' firefox_bookmarks_copie.html > copie4.html

which would result in creating empty file, as you fails to instruct GNU AWK to print changed line, logically it should be after change that is
awk '{gsub(/^ICON="[[:print:]]"$/,"");print}' firefox_bookmarks_copie.html > copie4.html

However this will now target only ICON with single-character value, that is for input file holding
STUFF
ICON="A"
ICON="ABC"
STUFF

would give output
STUFF

ICON="ABC"
STUFF

to target multi-character values too you might use + (one-or-more) following way
awk '{gsub(/^ICON="[[:print:]]+"$/,"");print}' firefox_bookmarks_copie.html > copie4.html

Now this assumes that ICON="..." spans whole line, I do not know if one might assume so without scrying EBNF notation describing what could be in files which you are processing.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)
